# Complex integration problem

Tags: complex-integration

Im having a bit trouble getting started in complex integrals.

Im integrating along a circle the integral $\int \frac{e^z}{z^2 + 1}$ where

a) center O radius 1/2
b) center i radius 1
c) center i radius 3

I have set $\gamma(t) = \frac{1}{2}e^{it}$ and $\gamma' = \frac{i}{2}e^{it}$ and $\gamma = z$ for part a) but how do I get around to doing the integral?

Comment: Where are you stuck? Also, do you know about the residue theorem?

Comment: Im stuck on integrating with respect to t. I have heard of the residue theorem but I dont know how to apply it

Comment: Cauchy's integral theorem or the Cauchy integral formula?

Comment: @user2750354 Please write the integrals you face into the question so we can see where the problem is.

Comment: How can this be done with Cauchys integral theorem?

Answer (score 1):

If you know the residue theorem, then these integrals may be done easily.  The integrand has poles at $z=i$ and $z=-i$.  In part a), neither pole is inside the contour, so the integral is zero. For part b), only the pole at $z=i$ is inside, so the integral is $i 2 \pi$ times the residue at $z=i$, or

$$i 2 \pi \frac{e^i}{2 i} = \pi (\cos{1} + i \sin{1})$$

In part c), both poles are inside the contour, so you will need to sum the residues at both poles.  I get that the integral is then $i 2 \pi \sin{1}$.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. How would this be done using Cauchys integral theorem?

Comment: @user2750354: Part a) is Cauchy's Theorem.  So technically are parts b) and c) - the residue theorem is merely an extension of Cauchy's theorem.

Comment: when I sum them together I get zero. What is the residue at z=-i

Comment: @user2750354: the residue there is $(e^{-i})/(-2 i)$.